# Changing an images size/resolution using struct and pointers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, pixel

we have been giving a task to complete at our school where we need to alter an image (invert colors, switch colors, rotate it by 90 degrees, double the size, zoom in on it) and right now I'm trying to double its size by doubling it's resolution but can't figure out how to access that address and change it.
We've been given two functions, one that can load an image and other that can save the image, so we don't need to worry about that, we've also been given two structs, one with rgb values and one with height and width(in pixels).

I've been looking around but haven't really found anything that works, or I'm just doing it wrong. I've also tried multiple things without success.

Here is my main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "studentFunctions.h"

int main()
{
    Image plain;
    char selection;
    readImage("test.png", &plain);

    printf("What do you wish to do?\nInvert colors = i.\nSwitch colors = s.\nDoulbe size = d.");
    scanf("%c", &selection);

    switch (selection)
    {

    case 'i':
        invertColor(plain);
        break;

    case 's':
        switchColor(plain);
        break;

    case 'd':
        makeBigger(plain);
        break;
    }

    printf("Saving PNG\n");
    writeImage("test.png", &plain);

    return 0;
    }
```

here is my function.c :

```
#include "studentFunctions.h"


void invertColor(Image plain)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < plain.height; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < plain.width; j++)
        {
            plain.pixels[i][j].r = 255 - (plain.pixels[i][j].r);
            plain.pixels[i][j].g = 255 - (plain.pixels[i][j].g);
            plain.pixels[i][j].b = 255 - (plain.pixels[i][j].b);
        }
    }
}

void switchColor(Image plain)
{
    int temp;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < plain.height; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < plain.width; j++)
        {
            temp = plain.pixels[i][j].r;

            plain.pixels[i][j].r = plain.pixels[i][j].b;
            plain.pixels[i][j].b = plain.pixels[i][j].g;
            plain.pixels[i][j].g = temp;
        }
    }
}

void makeBigger(Image* plain)
{
    *plain->height *= 2;
    *plain->width *= 2;

}
```

as you see I tried to point at the plain.height and plain.width to change the image resolution but this doesn't work. When hovering over "plain" it says "operand of '*' must be a pointer". What does this actually mean, and what is the correct way to do this?

The two functions we were giving looks like this:

```
void writeImage(char* filename, Image *img);
```

and

```
void readImage(char *filename, Image *img);
```

and the two structs we were giving are:

```
typedef struct image {
Pixel **pixels;
unsigned int height;
unsigned int width;
} Image;
```

and

```
typedef struct pixel {
uint8_t r;
uint8_t g;
uint8_t b;
} Pixel;
```

We can't edit or see the two given function nor the two structs.

Preferable I'd like an explanation of this and maybe a simple example, rather than a straight answer, as I am trying to learn and understand this. As last note I'm new to programming in general and especially in C, hope it's clear enough.
Thanks for answer.

Edit:
Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef STUDENTFUNCTIONS_H
#define STUDENTFUNCTIONS_H

#include <functions.h>

void invertColor(Image plain);
void switchColor(Image plain);
void makeBigger(Image* plain);

#endif
```

Comment: `*foo->bar` parses as `*(foo->bar)`.

Comment: The `->` is shortcut for `(*).` In your case `*plain->height` means `*(*plain).height` and that is one `*` too much. Just do `plain->height`.

Comment: "given two functions, one that can load an image and other that can save the image, so we don't need to worry about that" -->  Hmmm.  Try saving to a _different file.  `writeImage("test.png2", &plain);`

Comment: I maintain my simple image processing functions here https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc resizing can be done in lots of different ways. Easiest is to simply duplicate pixels to size by a power of two, but that gives very pixelly results.

Comment: `Image plain; makeBigger(plain);` and `void makeBigger(Image* plain)` do not work togather.  Compiler should have caught that.  Post `"studentFunctions.h"`.  I'd expect `makeBigger(&plain);`  (add &)

Comment: Thanks all, after changing to plain->height as well as makeBigger(&plain);
I'm still getting an error right when the image is saving, which is "Exception thrown: read access violation.
pixel was 0xEEEFFE." 
I thought maybe Image plain; should instead be Image* plain; but that gives the same error but with the address 0xB0EFFE.
I'm gonna add the header file as well.

Comment: Still saving to the same file `"test.png"`?.  Try just reading and writing the file.  No `invertColor();
        switchColor();
        makeBigger();`

Comment: `plain` is a struct, yet you sometimes pass it as pointer. You should pass it **always** as a pointer, and make it a pointer. Otherwise it will not be changed upon leaving the functions. If you want to access the width as pointer just access `plain->width`.

Comment: @UrielEli while I concur with the semantics of what you're describing, the OP's entrypoint for inverting color can be passed by value. The only thing that code does is change *dereferenced* data from the `pixels` member (a pointer), still leads to the same data, whether `plain` is passed by value or not. The `makeBigger` function modifies the value members of `Image`, and thusly is passed by address. While odd looking, this interface for `invertColor` and `switchColor` should work. That said, `makeBigger` is broken in multiple ways: wrong dereferencing, and no resizing of `pixels`.

Comment: Changing plain to a pointer (if changing "Image plain;" to "Image* plain;" changes it to a pointer) still gives me access violation, on "0xD7EFFE".
And yes I now save it as a new one "test2.png". Invert colors and switch colors work, though now it says " Stack around the variable 'plain' was corrupted." but they still work, as the new images colors is inverted.

Comment: @WhozCraig I haven't yet gotten to resizing pixels as I try to figure out how to higher the resolution of the image to be able to size the pixels, that's how thought of doing it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void makeBigger(Image* plain)
> {
>     *plain->height *= 2;
>     *plain->width *= 2;
>
> }
> ```
>
> I haven't yet gotten to resizing pixels as I try to figure out how to higher the resolution of the image to be able to size the pixels, that's how thought of doing it anyways.

In order *to higher the resolution of the image*, i. e. to enlarge it, it is not sufficient to make `plain->height` and `plain->width` (without the `*` before) bigger, rather it is also necessary to increase the allocated memory for the pixel row and column arrays - unless they'd already have been overallocated by `readImage()`, but the *read access violation* indicates they haven't. Yet we can't reliably determine how to reallocate the pixel memory whilst we don't know how the arrays have been originally allocated, so the given task is impossible to do with only the given information - a regrettable mistake of your teacher.